# How do I add a menu item which links to another edit view of an already defined resource in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I created two different `List` and `Edit` views of the same `Ressource` in react-admin. Both `List` views have a different filter applied and show different records by default.
The `Edit` views are different as well, because the second `Edit` view lets the user fill fields that are not shown on the first one.

The idea behind that are different workflow steps. You first craete a form and fill some basic information, andvance to the next workflow step and then add additional information without being able to change data from step one.

I tried to add the same `Ressource` twice with different `List` and `Edit` components but only one `Resource` shows up in the menu.

How can I add custom menu entries that link to the `List` view of an already defined  `Ressource`?

This does unfortunately not work:

```
  <Resource name="myResource" list={List1} edit={Edit1} create={Create1} options={{ label: 'Planning' }}  />
  <Resource name="myResource" list={List2} edit={Edit2}  options={{ label: 'Doing' }}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Resource name and "list, edit, show" keys use for URL path, so that is why you can't use resources with same names. You can resolve your problem doing custom menu and by adding custom routes.

**Menu documentation**: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#menu

**Custom routes**: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes

Comment: hmm, same link twice and it sais "menu" is deprecated. Do I really have to create a custom layout for that? Isn't there a way with less effort?

Comment: I created a custom layout, I used the example code from the documentation, but I get  an Error ````Error: Expected ref to be a function, a string, an object returned by React.createRef(), or null.````: I guess that's another issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right, link with custom routes fixed. Another way to reach what you want is create different resources and modify `dataProvider` for getting same API endpoint for different resource names. But this way is a little bit harder, as for me.

Comment: good point, thanks! since I already have a custom dataprovider which manages different APIs, it was easy to implement that the same endpoints are used for several 'virtual' resource names. Unfortunately  ````<Resource/>```` (which creates the menu entry) links to the unmapped resource name which does not exist.